# ¿Array.forEach no funciona en javascript?

Tags: javascript

He intentado iterar un array como éste:

```
import { Vec2 } from './Math.js';
import Physics from "./Physics.js";
export default class Entity{
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.pos = new Vec2(x, y);
    this.scale = new Vec2(w, h);
    this.vel = new Vec2;
    this.traits = [];
    this.traits['physics'] = new Physics;
  }
  addTraits(name, trait) {
    this.traits.push(trait);
  }
  updateTraits(deltaTime, level) {
    //this.traits["physics"].update(deltaTime, this, level);
    this.traits.forEach(trait => {
        trait.update(deltaTime, this, level);
    });
  }
}
```

Y no se ejecuta el `forEach` ni la función.

Comment: Ahora que caigo, estás preguntando afirmando que tampoco se llama al método `updateTraits()`. ¿Dónde o cuándo se espera que deba ser llamado dicho método? ¿Dónde estás usando este código?

Comment: Quizá tu pregunta real podría ser **¿por qué no se produce la llamada a `Entity.updateTraits()` en mi aplicación XX?**. Quedo a la espera de estos datos para reabrir mi respuesta.

Comment: No ese se llama desde otro archivo solo es que si yo pongo un console.log dentro del forEach no me sale en la consola y claramente tampoco se llama la funcion..

Comment: ¿Quién es el encargado de llamar a ese método? Si no se llama al método (la función) es porque no se está indicando correctamente que se ejecute éste. ¿Cuándo esperas que se ejecute?

Comment: `this.entity = new Entity();
this.entity.updateTraits(deltaTime, level);` Todo funciona de maravilla si pongo un console.log en la función de updateTraits funciona, pero si lo pongo dentro de el forEach no funciona.

Comment: Es lógico si no llamas a `addTraits()` nunca. Mira mi respuesta y lo entenderás.

Comment: Aquí esta el proyecto para que lo veas: https://github.com/FernandoGameYT/The-Wars-Legend/tree/master/public

Comment: ¿Has mirado mi respuesta? ¿Quieres trabajar con `Array` o con propiedades de clase? Si me respondes a eso te adapto el código a tu elección.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad al hacer `this.traits['physics']` estás definiendo una nueva propiedad de la clase (`this.traits.physics`) y no agregando datos al `Array`. La clase `Array` sólo permite usar `Array.forEach()` en los datos almacenados en ella, ignorando las propiedades que agregues.

Sin embargo podrás iterar por cada una de las propiedades (incluídos los datos del `Array`) a través de [`Reflect.ownKeys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys).

Ten en cuenta que `Array` tiene una propiedad predefinida que se llama `length` que contiene el número de elementos del array, tendrás que lidiar con su existencia.

En este ejemplo podrás comprobar estas afirmaciones.

```js
this.traits = [ 1, 2 ];
console.log('Tipo y constructor:', typeof this.traits, this.traits.constructor);
/* Esto agrega una propiedad a la instancia, y no un elemento al Array */
this.traits['physics'] = new Date();
/* Accedemos al contenido como si fuera una propiedad más */
console.log('Valor de la propiedad "physics":', this.traits.physics);
/* Agregamos más elementos al objeto de tipo Array */
this.traits.push(3);
this.traits.push(10);
/* Array.join unirá los elementos del Array, sin saber nada acerca de sus propiedades */
console.log('Unión:', this.traits.join(','));
/* Array.forEach navegará por los valores del Array, no por sus propiedades */
this.traits.forEach(trait => {
  console.log(trait);
});
/* Forma de iterar por sus propiedades */
Reflect.ownKeys(this.traits).forEach(clave => {
  console.log('Propiedad "' + clave + '"', this.traits[clave]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

proba con `$this=this`

```
updateTraits(deltaTime, level) {
    let $this= this;
    $this.traits.forEach(trait => {
        trait.update(deltaTime, this, level);
    });
}}
```

Comment: Investigando y probando me di cuneta que por una extraña razón ForEach no acepta arrays que tengan claves, pero gracias por tu intención.

Comment: @FernandoGameYt mmm puedes poner un ejemplo para verificar si no acepta

Comment: prueba esto y veras que no funciona: class Hola{
  update(msg){
    console.log(msg);
  }
}

var traits = [];

traits["physics"] = new Hola();

traits.forEach(trait => {
  trait.update("hola");
});